# Ajax in Asp.Net MVC strange behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My mark up has one `div` with `id= "divGrid"` and one ajax enabled form *outside* that `div`.  Form contains two text inputs and one submit button with `UpdateTargetId = "divGrid"`. It does update that grid perfectly but add duplicate ajax-enabled form on the page. Why this? How to fix this?

Here is my View:

```
@model List<EF.Models.Data.Books>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CodeFirst";
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<div id="divGrid">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ID</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            }
    </div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("name");
        <br />
        @Html.TextBox("price");
        <input type="submit" value="Insert" />    
    }
```

My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ViewResult CodeFirst(FormCollection form)
    {
        book.Name = form["name"];
        book.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(form["price"]);
        context.Books.Add(book);
        context.SaveChanges();
        result = context.Books.ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
```

Interestingly, my rendered mark-up is something like

```
<div id="divGrid">
    <div id="divGrid">
    <!-- Data display as expected -->
   </div>
   <!-- ajax enabled form, that is out side of this in source code -->
</div>
<!-- ajax enabled form, that is out side of this in source code -->
```

[image]

Comment: You need to return a partial view, not a view, and that partial view needs to render just the table data (not the same view you initially rendered)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I will try that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CodeFirst()` method is returning the same view you initially rendered and its being inserted inside the `<div id="divGrid">` which is why you see the form repeated. You need to return a separate partial view containing only the table. Create a separate child only method to display the initial table

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult BookTable()
{
  var model = context.Books; // no need for .ToList()
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

BookTable.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<EF.Models.Data.Books>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>@item.ID</td>
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td>@item.Price</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
}
```

Then create a view model for adding a new book so you can take advantage of MVC features such as strong type binding, client and server side validation etc.

```
public class BookVM
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and you controller methods become

```
public ActionResult CodeFirst()
{
  BookVM model = new BookVM();
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult CodeFirst(BookVM model)
{
    Book book = new Book(){ Name = model.Name, Price = model.Price };
    context.Books.Add(book);
    context.SaveChanges();
    result = context.Books();
    return PartialView("BookTable", result);
}
```

and change your view to

```
@model BookVM
....
<div id="divGrid">
  @Html.Action("BookTable");
</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divGrid", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
  .... // ditto for Price
  <input type="submit" value="Insert" />    
}
```

However this means your regenerating the html for the whole table everytime you submit the form. You would get far better performance by just using jquery and ajax to call a method that inserts the book and returns its new ID as json, then dynamically adding a new row to the table based on the returned ID, and the values from the textboxes in the form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, specially for recommending jquery ajax  in this scenario, obviously it be great performance enhancement. just want a little advice, when I am deleting something from table, jquery ajax is better or Ajax.BeginForm ?

Comment: jQuery and ajax are far better IMHO. `Ajax.BeginForm()` just means extra ovehead (loading the script). And you get far more control with the jQuery methods.

Comment: so which scenario it's better?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your asking? I'm saying using jQuery and ajax are better than using `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Comment: I am asking which situation `Ajax.BeginFor()` could be better? if not then what could be the reason razor have it.

Comment: IMO, there are no situations where it is better, and as far as I'm concerned its been obsolete for at least 5 years.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your time and valuable info sir :)